# AngularJS - Communicating with multiple instances of a directive from controllers.

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to find the best way to pass data to a directive from any controller.

I have a directive called `sideMenu`. There will be 2 of these on the screen at any one time. Each can have its own ID.

I need to pass 2 pieces of information into the directive from any of my controllers, an ID and a `string`.

Typically this would be done with a service/factory and I would simply `DI` my service into any of the controllers that wish to communicate with the directive, though because they (services) are singleton it doesn't really work in my case - if i, from a controller, need to communicate with both `sideMenu`'s then they both get the most recent data added to the service.

How else can I, from any given controller, pass data to 2 separate instances of the same directive?

The directive's would be outside of the scope of other controllers - the directives would be in the top most parent scope (I have some nested controllers).

Would I be better to set a couple of properties on the `$rootScope` for each directive and manipulate them as-and-when?

Comment: you can inject the service into the directive as normal. Don't mess with `$rootScope`, if you injected the same service into the controller too then you have communication between directives and between controller and directives.

Comment: That works if all your directives using the service need the same data - though I need to pass one set of data to one directive and another set to another directive and would rather not make multiple services - this make sense?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22234018/how-do-you-pass-parameters-to-an-angularjs-factory/22234220#22234220
You could instantiate several factory objects and bind them to directives through attributes.

Comment: Using events (`$rootScope.$broadcast()`, then `$scope.$on()` from the controller of the directive) may solve your problem. You can use the name of the event to differentiate between the 2 components (e.g. `$rootScope.$broadcast("leftMenu",...)`, `$rootScope.$broadcast("rightMenu",...)`).

Comment: @JoeMinichino - thank you for your link. In order to use that idea I would essentially be creating a new instance of my service/factory and then have to attach the instance to a property ,on a scope that the directive can see wouldn't I?

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos - yep, for sure, I have it working using `$broadcast` though felt for sure there would be a more elegant solution?

Comment: @Darren yes, if your service is called `SideMenuInfo` i would have a `$scope.smInfo1 = new SideMenuInfo` (etc. for as many you need) and pass that as an ngModel to the directive. That way you may expand your factory function without having to bind each attribute to the directive individually.

Comment: I am curious why do you think events are not elegant. I don't know if this is the place for such a conversation though :)

Comment: @JoeMinichino - many thanks. I'm now starting to implement this idea. I will create a new instance and attach it to a property on startup and then communicate with the instances methods where needed.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos - events are awesome. Just looking for a way where I don't bog down a huge project with masses of them is all.